# MAF: Add-in crashes host even when run in seperate process

Tags: add-in, maf

I am using MAF for my Addin development. All seems to be working fine, but one issue needs be sorted...

I activate the plugin in their own process, i,e, using

var process = new AddInProcess();
myAddinToken.Activate(process,AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);

When an unhandled exception occurs in the add-in, my host crashes!
Since i am running the addin in a seperate process, why i am i still seeing my host app crash because of an unhandled exception in the ad-in?

Is it not supposed to simply crash the add-in specific dedicated process, and leave the host process as-is live?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception that crashes your app?

Do you have an UI element coming from your AddIn?

With the UI I had to close / dispose the UI elements on the host side properly and also catch RemotingException

Maybe this helps you a bit:

```
AddInToken grailAddInToken = addInTokens[0];
AddInProcess addInProcess = new AddInProcess();
addInProcess.Start();
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(addInProcess.ProcessId);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (s, e) => synchronizationService.Invoke(() =>
{
     window.Close();
});
```